# PHRoute can't route to controller 'Class not found '

Tags: php

Having never used a router before outside of a traditional framework I've become a little stuck with PHRoute and routing to a controller. My code is as follows, I have a index.php which includes config files and bootstrap/app.php which contents are as follows:

```
require_once('../application/controllers/home.php');
$router = $app['router'];
$router->any('/home', ['Home','Application/Controllers/Home']);

function processInput($uri){        
        $uri = implode('/', 
            array_slice(
                explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 1));         

            return $uri;    
    }

use Phroute\Phroute\Dispatcher;

$dispatcher =  new Dispatcher($router->getData());

$response = $dispatcher->dispatch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], processInput($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

echo $response;
```

The problem is it can't find my home controller when I hit the /home route

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Home' not found in /application/vendor/phroute/phroute/src/Phroute/HandlerResolver.php:16
```

In the above code I have done a simple require so I know the class is defiantly loaded into the script. The class looks like the following:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controllers;

class Home
{

    public function __construct(){
        echo 'home construct';
    }

    public function index(){
        echo 'index';
    }

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possibly because your using a namespace, try using `Application\Controllers\Home` with back slashes.

Comment: @NigelRen Yeah I gave that a go but no luck. I have tried newing up the Home class (before the routing) and it works fine so the class is defiantly being included

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your route definition. The phroute documentation says:

> // Lazy load autoloaded route handling classes using strings for classnames
>
> // Calls the Controllers\User::displayUser($id) method with {id} parameter as  an argument
>
> $router->any('/users/{id}', ['Controllers\User','displayUser']);

Your route definition should be the classname (including the namespace) followed by the method to be invoked:

```
$router->any('/home', ['Application\Controllers\Home', 'index']);
```